# EZLoadingActivity giving issue on Carthage Update in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, carthage

I have opened project after 5 months.

Setup it in new macbook. Cloned porject.

Now when i go to set dependencies using Carthage. Cartfile is same is before and code was working 5 months ago.

now i am able to get all my dependencies. But EZLoadingActivity giving error on carthage update.

Pasting terminal console here:

```
*** Building scheme "EZLoadingActivity_iOS" in EZLoadingActivity.xcodeproj
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 65:
/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/mac/Git/project-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/EZLoadingActivity/EZLoadingActivity.xcodeproj -scheme EZLoadingActivity_iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/mac/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.3_10G8/EZLoadingActivity/2.1 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/gb/tm7hcwvs05s3zkqdp1lndwgm0000gn/T/EZLoadingActivity SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/mac/Git/project-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/EZLoadingActivity)
This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/gb/tm7hcwvs05s3zkqdp1lndwgm0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.hbqgmp.log
```

Also pasting logs as mentioned here /var/folders/gb/tm7hcwvs05s3zkqdp1lndwgm0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.hbqgmp.log

```
 /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/mac/Git/arteciate-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/EZLoadingActivity/EZLoadingActivity.xcodeproj -scheme EZLoadingActivity_iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/mac/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.3_10G8/EZLoadingActivity/2.1 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/gb/tm7hcwvs05s3zkqdp1lndwgm0000gn/T/EZLoadingActivity SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/mac/Git/arteciate-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/EZLoadingActivity)User defaults from command line:
IDEArchivePathOverride = /var/folders/gb/tm7hcwvs05s3zkqdp1lndwgm0000gn/T/EZLoadingActivity
IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/mac/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.3_10G8/EZLoadingActivity/2.1

Build settings from command line:
CARTHAGE = YES
CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
SDKROOT = iphoneos12.4
SKIP_INSTALL = YES
STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT = NO

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'EZLoadingActivity_iOS')

Build system information
error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'EZLoadingActivity_iOS')
```

Please guide me how to resolve it so i can use EZLoadingActivity libraray in my project and can able to run my project.